# C# LINQ: Get items with max price

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a list of my objects:

```
class MyObj
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }
    public String OtherData { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<MyObj> {
 new MyObj { Title = "AAA", Price = 20, OtherData = "Z1" },
 new MyObj { Title = "BBB", Price = 20, OtherData = "Z2" },
 new MyObj { Title = "AAA", Price = 30, OtherData = "Z5" },
 new MyObj { Title = "BBB", Price = 10, OtherData = "Z10" },
 new MyObj { Title = "CCC", Price = 99, OtherData = "ZZ" }
};
```

What is the best way to get list with unique Title and MAX(Price).
Resulting list needs to be:

```
var ret = new List<MyObj> {
 new MyObj { Title = "BBB", Price = 20, OtherData = "Z2" },
 new MyObj { Title = "AAA", Price = 30, OtherData = "Z5" },
 new MyObj { Title = "CCC", Price = 99, OtherData = "ZZ" }
};
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, you could do:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(x => x.Title)
                .Select(group =>
                {
                    decimal maxPrice = group.Max(x => x.Price);
                    return group.Where(x => x.Price == maxPrice)
                                .First();
                };
```

If you need LINQ to SQL (where you can't use statement lambdas) you could use:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(x => x.Title)
       .Select(group => group.Where(x => x.Price == group.Max(y => y.Price))
                             .First());
```

Note that in LINQ to Objects that would be less efficient as in each iteration of `Where`, it would recompute the maximum price.

Adjust the `.First()` part if you want to be able return more than one item with a given name if they both have the same price.

Within LINQ to Objects you could also use [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com)'s [`MaxBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) method:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(x => x.Title)
                .Select(group => group.MaxBy(x => x.Price));
```

Comment: Thanks for perfect explanation :)

Comment: Dude, even though this is old, it just helped me out perfectly! You are so awesome in roman times they would have built temples to worship you.....then probably killed you because they were superstitious fickle people back then.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ret = list.GroupBy(x => x.Title)
              .Select(g => g.Aggregate((a, x) => (x.Price > a.Price) ? x : a));
```

(And if you need the results to be a `List<T>` rather than an `IEnumerable<T>` sequence then just tag a `ToList` call onto the end.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var ret = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price).GroupBy(x => x.Title).Select(@group => @group.ElementAt(0)).ToList();
```

this should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to mention that

```
var query = list.GroupBy(x => x.Title)
       .Select(group => group.Where(x => x.Price == group.Max(y => y.Price))
       .First());
```

Should be

```
var query = list.GroupBy(x => x.Title)
       .First(group => group.Where(x => x.Price == group.Max(y => y.Price)));
```

I like the Richard solution to **greatest-n-per-group** problem.

```
var query = list
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Price)    //set ordering
    .GroupBy(o => o.Title)              //set group by
    .Select(o => o.First());            //take the max element
```

However it needs to be slightly modified

```
var query = list
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Price)                       //set ordering
    .GroupBy(o => o.Title)                                 //set group by
    .Select(o => o.Where(k => k.Price == o.First().Price)) //take max elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Usinng *MaxBy* will make it simple.

```
var list = list.GroupBy(g => g.Title)
           .Select(s => 
           {
              return s.MaxBy(x => x.Price);
           }).ToList();
```